# UWP ScrollViewer inside a SplitView.Content not scrolling

Tags: xaml, uwp, scrollviewer

I´m trying to build a UWP app and I have the follow components:

MainPage:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Name="TituloStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="HamburguerButton" Content="&#xE700;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Height="50" Width="50" Click="HamburguerButton_Click"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Titulo" Text="Estrutura de Dados" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <SplitView Name="PrincipalSplitView" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False"
               CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="200" Grid.Row="1">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Name="ListasButton" Content="L" Width="50" Height="50" Click="ListasButton_Click"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Listas" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Name="PilhasButton" Content="P" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Pilhas" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Name="FilasButton" Content="F" Width="50" Height="50"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Filas" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
        <SplitView.Content>
            <TextBlock Text="SplitView Content" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </SplitView.Content>
    </SplitView>
</Grid>
```

The next Page will be loaded inside the Content of the SplitView.

```
<Page>
  <Grid>

  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Background="Cyan" Grid.Column="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <RelativePanel Padding="20" MaxHeight="700" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <A lot of Components: TextBlocks, TextBoxes, RadioButtons, ... />
      </RelativePanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

The ScrollViewer should work as a Toolbar on the right side of the window. But when I resize the window, the vertical scroll not works.

Full screen:
[image: Page in full screen]

Resized:
[image: Page resized]

Comment: Is the `RelativeLayout` a custom Control? What is it for?

Comment: Did you resize the windows size bigger  enough  so that the scroll bar is no needed.

Comment: @Sunteen-MSFT, but when I resize the window to a smaller size, the scroll doesn´t work too.

Comment: @ThomasSchneiter, thanks for observation! It´s a RelativePanel.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. When i add a StackPanel with simple Rectangles (combined Height > 700) inside of the RelativePanel, the ScrollViewer works as you want it to. Is there a reason for using a RelativePanel with `MaxHeight="700"`?. Content of the Panel that comes after 700 will be hidden this way.

Comment: @ThomasSchneiter, no, there´s no reason! With Height or without it, the scroll doesn´t work.

Comment: How do you arrange the Components inside of the Panel? Maybe try to use a Stackpanel instead of the RelativePanel since you just stack Components vertically anyway. My guess is that the ScrollViewer's height doesen't resize to the page height.

Comment: I didn´t said but the Page is loaded inside a SplitView.Content. Do you believe that´s the problem, @ThomasSchneiter?

Comment: I think the problem is because your SplitView is in the Row with the `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>`. This makes the SplitView higher than the Screen and does not scroll as a result. Use `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>` for this row to make it as high as the screen is. Remove the last RowDefinition if you don't need it.

Comment: @ThomasSchneiter, YOU ARE THE MAN!!! Thanks very much!

Comment: No problem. I added it as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because your SplitView is in the Row with the `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>`. This makes the SplitView higher than the Screen and does not scroll as a result.
Use `<RowDefinition Height="*"/>` for this row to make it as high as the screen is.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<SplitView Grid.Row="1">
    ....
</SpitView>
```